# Azure DevOps Pipelines - .NET Core Solution with Multiple Projects - How to do a single build and multiple project publishes?

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently, I have a pipeline set up for this .NET Core solution, composed of several project apps, but I'm building each "deliverable project" independently (REST APIs, gRPC APIs, ASP.NET Core MVC apps and so on - one `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build`, `dotnet test`, `dotnet publish`, `docker build` and `docker push` tasks for each executable in this solution). It works.

Each "project sub-pipeline" is an "Agent Job" inside of the main pipeline. It's required by the client that I build the projects with the `win-x64` RID and pack each App/API in Windows Containers (dotnet CLI doesn't allow passing a RID to build a whole solution - error NETSDK1134).

The question is: How could I do a single restore/build/test cycle for the whole solution (to improve build time) and only have the publish steps separated for each project?

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117098/azure-devops-build-pipeline-for-solution-with-multiple-project-types) but I think it is a different thing. Could you guys point me to some docs where I could find more info related to my case?

I researched a bit about MSBuild Publish Profiles and custom MSBuild projects but didn't manage to find something similar.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a single `restore/build/test` you need to publish your whole source folder as an artifact then in your artifact you will get your code and build assemblies. Then reuse this artifact for later steps. It could look like:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'my-vsts-feed' # A series of numbers and letters

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'solution'
```

then on deployment job you will get whole solution with restored packages and build code ready for further steps.

Regarding .NET RID as far as I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) you have two options:

- A single RID can be set in the  element of your project file.
- pass it with `--runtime` to dotnet build

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the RID (win-x64), how should I deal with it in the context of building an entire solution instead of a per-project RID indication?

Comment: Hey Krzysztof, thank you for your prompt reply. The problem that I'm facing is that when I pass a specific runtime, I get the error I mentioned in the question (NETSDK1134, saying that If I would like to specify a RID, I should compile the projects individually instead of a whole solution). How should I circumvent that?

Comment: You will find some workadound for this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14281#issuecomment-876510589). And si you can see this is an issue already repoerte don GitHub.